# Something blocks lftp from connecting to remote FTP server

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, lftp

I'm running command in Ubuntu 16.04 Server:
`lftp -c "set net:max-retries 1; set ftp:ssl-allow off; open -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST; ls ./public_html/testing;"` (variables are predefined)

But all I get is `ls ./public_html/testing' at 0 [Making data connection...]` running continuously.

I have `ufw` turned off and I tried to connect with `ftp` command and it works fine.

What might be wrong in the server setting?